Errors when including basic libraries in a default Actor subclass (UE5)
I'm new on C++ development, especially under the UE5 toolchain. I'm following an online course on it right now, and as it started teaching how to use C++ on it, it had an error which isn't treated in the course.
As a programmer (but in other langs), I see it's an error when importing external libraries, but as I'm still unaware on how C++ handles this, I'm a bit lost. These #imports appear on a simple scaffolding C++ class file, created from UE5 itself (when attempting to create an Actor class):
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MovingPlatform.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class OBSTACLEASSAULT_API AMovingPlatform : public AActor

// rest of the class (not needed rn)

All three #import lines throw the same error:

#include errors detected. Consider updating your compile_commands.json or includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

I'm not sure where these files are, what do I have to change, or even, if there are any important things I should know first about how C++ handles files/libraries. Any tips on how to understand it, and how to fix it, so it reaches those files? I think the setup of the project is fine (downloaded .NET 6, the regular Visual Studio for compiling, and added the Game tools for C++ optional dependency. I think that should suffice, or am I missing something?
Thank you a lot.

That looks like a Visual Studio Code error. Why aren't you using Visual Studio, if you've already installed it? (Despite the similar names, the two products are completely unrelated.)

Also, "#import" is not the same thing as "#include".

Yeah well, but the instructor stated that he prefers VSCode for this purpose. I'm also more used to it, coming from a JS background. I guess it's just better to use regular VS?

I personally use VS with a keyboard shortcut that opens a file in my Editor Of Choice, which I have found leads to less faffing about with annoying configuration files.

Using VSCode is fine. Unless you generate the project specifically for VSCode (by following the steps here: https://dev.epicgames.com/documentation/en-us/unreal-engine/setting-up-visual-studio-code-for-unreal-engine), VSCode will issue quite a few errors that are, in fact, not errors. Did you try building and launching?
